# Coordinate free supersymmetric sigma model Lagrangian

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, quantum-field-theory, mirror-symmetry, supermanifolds

I would like to know if there is a coordinate free version of the Lagrangian of the supersymmetric sigma model on a $2$-dimensional spacetime, with target space a Kähler manifold. The action for this theory is
$$S=\int_\Sigma\frac{1}{2}g_{ij}(\partial_z\phi^i\partial_{\bar{z}}\phi^{\bar{j}}+\partial_z\phi^{\bar{j}}\partial_{\bar{z}}\phi^i)+\sqrt{-1}g_{i\bar{j}}\psi_-^{\bar{j}}D_z\psi_-^i+\sqrt{-1}g_{i\bar{j}}\psi_+^{\bar{j}}D_{\bar{z}}\psi_+^i+R_{i\bar{j}k\bar{l}}(\psi_+^i\psi_+^{\bar{j}}\psi_-^k\psi^{\bar{l}}_-)dz\wedge d\bar{z}$$
Here, $\phi:\Sigma\to X$ is a map from the Riemann surface into the Kähler manifold, and the $\phi^i$ are local coordinates on $X$. The $\psi_\pm^i$ are "fermionic coordinates", i.e. sections of a spinor bundle over $\Sigma$. This is the way it is stated in many sources: "Mirror Symmetry" and "Mirror Symmetry and Dirichlet Branes" from the Clay Mathematics Institute, "Mirror Symmetry and Algebraic Geometry" by Cox and Katz, "Classical Mirror Symmetry" by Jinzenji and "Mirror Symmetry" by Voisin, to name a few. All of these are written by mathematicians. Yet, none of these books contain a coordinate free version of this action.

In its present form, I have no intuition for what this action really represents, geometrically. Obviously, the first summand is just the volume of $\Sigma$ with respect to the pullback metric $\phi^*g$. Similarly, it seems like the two summands that follow could be cast into an expression like $\text{Re}\langle\psi_-,\nabla_Z\psi_-\rangle$ for some bilinear form on the space of spinors, obtained from the metric $g$, similar to the Dirac Lagrangian from the standard model. However, it is not clear to me how to translate these indices into coordinate free notation. Is this possible to do? Are there any sources which do explore this topic in a coordinate free way? This may be my own shortcoming, but I find that the swamp of indices heavily impedes my understanding of what is actually going on.